# css pseudoclass:hover not working

Tags: css, hover, pseudo-class

I am struggling to get a simplest css hover pseudoclass to work. Anybody knows why the following doesnt work?

the css

```
#hidden {display:none;}
#show:hover #hidden{display:block;}
```

the html

```
<a href="#" id="show">show</a>
<div id="hidden">here i am</div>
```

I really feel stupid asking such a simple question, i did this a hunderd times, but cant figure out why this shouldnt work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this

```
#show:hover + #hidden{display:block;}
```

`:hover #hidden` implies that `#hidden` is a child of the hover element. The `+` selector looks for the next adjacent sibling.

Comment: You saved the day (two years later)!

Comment: >The + selector looks for the next adjacent sibling.
So, how to display #hidden when it is BEFORE of #show?