# Weird rendering bug in desktop webkit (safari/chrome) with absolutely positioned elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, webkit

If you look at the video here: http://f.cl.ly/items/2g1a2B3G312D0x0G353W/Render%20Bug%202.mov - you will see the problem in action. Basically, I have something along the following:

```
<section id="sidenav">
  <h1>TEXT HERE</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>Tab One</li>
    <li>Tab Two</li>
    <li>Tab Three</li>
    <li>Tab Four</li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tab"></div>
</section>
```

Sidenav is absolutely positioned, like this:

```
#sidenav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 770px;
  padding: 30px 0px 20px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85);
  -webkit-transition: left 0.75s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 10; /* This fixed it. */
}

#sidenav.hidden {
  left: -768px;
}
```

I have the following jQuery:

```
$("#tab").click(function(){
  $("#sidenav").toggleClass("hidden");
});
```

However, the elements inside of the section aren't keeping up with the animation. Whenever I click, they either lag behind or don't move at all. However, they are just ghosts, I can't click them. When I bring the side nav back out, they usually catch up, but sometimes they are broken until I hover over the `<li>`'s.

Keep in mind, this only happens in Safari/Chrome on the desktop. Safari on the iPad and Firefox on the desktop are working fine.

Thanks!
Andrew

---

**EDIT WITH FIX:**

So apparently adding z-index: 10 (or any z-index) to the sidenav element fixed the problem. Some people were asking for the entirety of my css, so I edited the post to contain it. I'm not sure exactly why z-index fixed this, and I'd love to know why. I'm still offering my bounty to whomever can explain that. Thanks!

Comment: have you tried doing the sliding using jquery instead of css3? this could be css3 support bug kind of thing. If you have not tried that I would suggest to go that route for now

Comment: I want to avoid jQuery for this, because CSS3 animations are sprinkled throughout and are much more efficient.

Comment: well efficient as it might be, you still got this problem. can you give the code/css for the arrows? maybe you need to put the animation on them as well if they are positioned differently (not static)

Comment: This is just a guess, but might the position of the `<ul>` element (and its contents) be **static**? Have you tried setting `position:relative` on `<ul>` and `<li>`s? Regardless, it seems like a rendering bug.

Comment: No, they are purely left on the screen. I can't interact with them and when I inspect them they aren't actually there.

Comment: Sounds like a css3 support bug to me. In my opinion swap to jQuery (for backwards compatibility with older browsers)

Comment: Could you post some more of your code? Maybe you could make a fiddle on jsfiddle.net to recreate the error?

Comment: yeah it looks like a bug to me.

Comment: I would nearly bet this is a CSS positioning misdeclaration. Please post the complete CSS of the section all elements within that section. What you posted is not enough.

Comment: Could you post the CSS for `#tab` please, perhaps there is also some like `#sidenav .hidden #tab` which I would assume is the issue or infact `#sidenav .hidden` should be `#sidenav.hidden`

Comment: Webkit uses z-index when doing transitions, right? Imagine if you have two elements on a different z-index that animate toward one another. Should they passthrough or block?

Comment: I did some research and found http://css3pie.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=2062 which says you can use `-pie-poll:true;' Tell me if this helps anyone.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So apparently adding z-index: 10 (or any z-index) to the sidenav element fixed the problem. Some people were asking for the entirety of my css, so I edited the post to contain it. I'm not sure exactly why z-index fixed this, and I'd love to know why. I'm still offering my bounty to whomever can explain that. Thanks!

Comment: OH MY GOSH!!! Thank you!!!!! I've been banging my head for hours now trying to figure out why my app was working fine in IE and Firefox but messed up like you demonstrated in all webkit based browsers. Stupid that all it takes is a z-index. Gah! Thank you again.

Comment: I used `z-index: 1;` and it worked perfectly, what an odd fix.

Comment: Had a different bug with weird color rendering of list item `li` elements' background-color on hover.  when hovering on different items, portions of different size of the nav would take on a slightly different color tone than the background color that is set.  REMOVING `z-index` from the main `nav` container element helped for some reason.  PS: Everything else besides `<li>`'s is transparent.  This makes no sense to me.  I suspect a bug.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to post this as a comment, but since I'm a newbie here, my only option is posting this as an answer. In the video example you posted the hover over the list elements allowed for the display of the arrows, but they did not go away on mouse out. If you are trying to do this purely with css and not have the latent images, you should use hover.

That is detailed in this post:
[Using only CSS, show div on hover over <a>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210033/show-div-on-hover-with-only-css)

That way, if you hide the arrows as the mouse leaves the list element, there will not be any arrow to stay behind when the list slides off the page to the left.

Comment: I want the arrow there the whole time. It is simply absolutely positioned to the right of the <li>. The fact that it is jumping around shouldn't be happening :(

Comment: @andrewpthorp, how about try to use float:right instead of left: for buttons?

Answer (score 1):

from the markup you have given it looks like the class"hidden" will also take your 'nav' div with it (it is inside sidenav ) - I imagine that would cause some quirky

As a rule of thumb

- markup the content
- style up
- add the interactions ( click events and behaviours )
- THEN add your final interaction candy ( easing etc )

( doing this you should identify which part is causing the problem in the ui )

Comment: Yes, I agree. You are setting "hidden" class on the #sidenav, but your CSS applies the hidden position to children of #sidenav, not #sidenav itself.

Comment: Whoops, that was just a mistake in my pasting my code. I'm using SASS and I converted it to standard CSS for this question. It should have read #sidenav.hidden

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes this works: make the parent `position:relative` its like webkit's version of the old ie haslayout bug.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by removing the z-index style from the parent and giving a z-index higher than 0 to the fixed element.
Hope this works with others.