# Show div on hover with CSS

Tags: html, css

I would like to show a hidden div "delete-button" contained within the div "post-wrap", when I hover over it (#post-wrap). How Can I do this with CSS?

Here is what I have done so far:
http://jsfiddle.net/ksvrY/2/

```
#delete-button{
position: absolute;
right: 10px;
top: 10px;
margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
height: 30px;
width: 225px;
overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: May be duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210033/show-div-on-hover-with-only-css

Answer (score 0):

See: http://jsfiddle.net/ksvrY/4/

```
   #post-wrap:hover #delete-button{
        display:inherit;
    }
```

also hide the button:

```
#delete-button{
        display:none;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
#post-wrap:hover #delete-button { 
     display:block;    
}

#delete-button { display:none; }
```

...and if you wanna get nice with it (append necessary vendor-prefixes as appropriate):

```
#post-wrap:hover #delete-button { 
     opacity:1;    
}

#delete-button { -webkit-transition:all 1s ease-in; opacity:0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#button-delete {display: none;}
#post-wrap:hover #button-delete {display: block;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ksvrY/5/

Answer (score 0):

and its working now :)

the html

```
<div id="post-wrap">
    <div id="delete-button">
        <button id="button-delete"><p> Remove </p></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

the CSS

```
#post-wrap {
    position: relative;
    margin: 20px 0px 0px 20px;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 150px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    background-color: #fff;
/*  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.247059) 0px 3px 8px 0px; */
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0px 1px 3px 0px
}

#delete-button{
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 225px;
    overflow: auto;
}

#button-delete {
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
    height: 30px;
    width: auto;
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    background-color: #eee;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0px 1px 3px 0px;
    display:none;
}

#button-delete p {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    font-family: calibri;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #444;
}

#post-wrap:hover #button-delete{
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use hover

http://jsfiddle.net/Ptxfy/

```
#post-wrap:hover #delete-button { 
     display:block;    
}

#delete-button { display:none; }
```

I would not use the direct child selector as it is not necessary and can lead to problems down the road.

Comment: I appreciate it isn't necessary (since it's an ID), but out of curiosity, what problems are you referring to?

Comment: you could end up packing the button in a wrapper, or some js might do that and then it isnt a direct child anymore.

Comment: Ah, from a maintainability stand point; thats fair. Considering that the CSS is using an ID, my rationale when writing it was: direct child with an **ID** wouldn't suffer from such a refactor.

Comment: yes thats the rationale. Also some tribesman in the jungle might be viewing the website on IE6 and then it wont work ;)