# How to hover a div and hover some elements?

Tags: html, css, parameters

I want that when the mouse stay over of the `div` `hello`, the paragraph with class `nice_day` and image dont be affected.

How should do it using css3?

```
<div class="hello">
  <div class="stack"><img src="1.png"/></div>
  <div class="overflow"><p class="ilove"><img src="2.png"/>Im a text</p>
       <p class ="programming"Im other text</p>
         <div class="Have">
             <img src="3.png"/>
            <p class="nice_day"></p>
         </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210033/show-div-on-hover-with-only-css

Comment: paragraph and image are affected in what way? Please provide you CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Option #1 - Add Selectively

This approach looks at the `:hover` state of the ancestor and only adds styles where desired.

1. Simple: http://jsfiddle.net/gF7Ju/2/
2. Multiple Elements: http://jsfiddle.net/gF7Ju/3/

**CSS**

```
/* just for formatting so we can see the boxes */

.hello {
    border: 1px solid red;    
}

.hello > div {
    padding: 6px;
    border: 1px solid silver;
}

/* 

Selector(s) here to determine which element(s) should be impacted by the
parent's hover, and which should not.

*/

.hello:hover div:first-child {
    background-color: yellow;    
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="hello">
    <div>Hover effect</div>
    <div>No hover effect</div>
</div>
```

### Option #2 - Cancel/Ignore Selectively

Depending on what properties should be modified on hover, you could apply the hover style to the ancestor and then restyle the children (e.g. setting `background-color` to white, even though the parent's hovered background is yellow).

I prefer the first approach where possible.

Comment: theres a way wihout use first-child selector? like, selecting only the second option?

Comment: Sure, *any* selector is valid. I'll add another example for you.

Comment: Oh that is great! :D Thank you so much by your answer! :}

Comment: Just another quickly quest, is there a way to add a hover in 2 div without be parent? like hover in a div-left and div-right?

Comment: no 2 div separately without be a family, like div-hello1 and div-hello2. when i put mouse over div-hello1, div-hello2 be hover also, understand?

Comment: No, i mean like this `<div class="hello1">..content</div> <div class="hello2">..content</div>`. When i hover hello1, hello2 will be affected too. that is not possible? must be inside a div father?

Comment: Sort of, with the adjacent sibling selector (`+`). It only works in one direction though, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/gF7Ju/6/, because CSS selectors typically can't look *ahead*, only behind.

Answer (score 0):

**IF** you want to keep styles of child elements on hover of parent element, you need to *cancel* the parent style like following

```
.hello{text-decoration: underline;}
.hello:hover img, .hello:hover .nice_day{text-decoration: none}
```

Note that we're setting `text-decoration: none` for the children elements, `img`; and `.nice_day` in case they get underlined when `.hello` is hovered.

Answer (score 0):

you can set again your default css to `p.nice_day` :

```
div.hello:hover p.nice_day{
   //your default css of .nice_day
}
```