# Hover at image and show link at that image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have div in the manner as shown below which are generated by loop.
I want to show that `quick` `div` at hovering over the `image` or hovering `over the div` but when I hover it shows div all over the other divs. Any suggestion please.

```
<div class="box-product">
    <div>
        <div class="image"><a href="">test 1<img src="image.jpg" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="quick" style="display: none;">Quick Look</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="image"><a href="">test 2<img src="image.jpg" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="quick" style="display: none;">Quick Look</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="image"><a href="">test 3<img src="image.jpg" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="quick" style="display: none;">Quick Look</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="image"><a href="">test 4<img src="image.jpg" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="quick" style="display: none;">Quick Look</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my jQuery

```
$(function () {
    $(".box-product div").each(function () {
        $(".image").mouseenter(function () {
            $(".quick").show();
        });
        $(".image").mouseout(function () {
            $(".quick").hide();
        });
    });
});
```

I have created a [jsfidle](http://jsfiddle.net/husnainahmed/5unMB/13/)  which clearly defines what is my question.

Comment: Did you consider using pure CSS? See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210033/show-div-on-hover-with-only-css

Comment: Doing it with **css** is really good option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this script:

```
$(function () {
    $(".image").each(function () {
        $(this).mouseenter(function () {
            $(this).parent().find(".quick").show();
        });
        $(this).mouseout(function () {
            $(this).parent().find(".quick").hide();
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

see that for the change i think you ask that one

look at

```
$(function () {
$(".box-product div").each(function () {
    $(".image").mouseenter(function(){
       $(this).parents().eq(0).find(".quick").show();
    });
    $(".image").mouseout(function(){
       $(this).parents().eq(0).find(".quick").hide();
    });
});});
```

> http://jsfiddle.net/5unMB/19/

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$('div.image').each(function(){
       $(this).on('hover',function(){
          $('div.quick').css('display','none');
          $(this).next().css('display','block');
       });                    
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5unMB/18/

Comment: Really a helpful answer. I did it with css and it worked like I desire :) Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change your html to contain nested divs:

```
<div class="box-product">
 <div class="image"><a href="">test 1<img src="image.jpg" /></a>
<div class="quick" style="display: none;">
    Quick Look
    </div>
</div>

 <div class="image"><a href="">test 2<img src="image.jpg" /></a>
<div class="quick" style="display: none;">
    Quick Look
    </div>
</div>

 <div class="image"><a href="">test 3<img src="image.jpg" /></a>
<div class="quick" style="display: none;">
    Quick Look
    </div>
</div>

 <div class="image"><a href="">test 4<img src="image.jpg" /></a>
<div class="quick" style="display: none;">
    Quick Look
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Then you can change your jQuery at the following way:

```
$(function () {
    $(".box-product div").each(function () {
        $(".image").mouseenter(function(){
           $(this).find('.quick').show();
        });
        $(".image").mouseout(function(){
           $(this).find('.quick').hide();
        });
    });
  });
```

look at the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/husnainahmed/5unMB/13/