# CSS - show / hide content with anchor name

Tags: css, hide, anchor

**Single page website**

I have a single page website (one page only). I can navigate with a menu to get to different parts of the page with anchor name, just like (see sidebar):

[WordPress Docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

**Hide the other stuff**

I want to hide stuff that does not belong the the current active page part and just show the information of the part that I'm looking at.

**Question(s)**

- Can I hide stuff that is not a part of the current #anchor_part with only CSS?
- Have you seen any sites already doing this?

Comment: Just with CSS, no.  You'll require Javascript.  And have I seen other sites do "this."  It's hard to say.  It'd be helpful to see what you're actually trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/hqnjW/)**

Try this Html

```
<a href="#a">a</a>
<a href="#b">b</a>
<a href="#c">c</a>

<div id="a" class="page"> this is a id</div>
<div id="b" class="page"> this is b id</div>
<div id="c" class="page"> this is c id</div>
```

and Css

```
#a, #b, #c{
    display:none;
}
#a:target{
    display:block;
}
#b:target{
    display:block;
}
#c:target{
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: See https://quirksmode.org/css/selectors/target.html (seems to be CSS2, though seeing https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3 at first I thought it was CSS3 only - maybe they've augmented it at CSS3)

Comment: thanks - combined this with :hover at https://jsfiddle.net/birbilis/23nt74se/ - with a small difference, I just set the anchor to jump to itself for easier maintenance of IDs and targets)

Comment: ...and maintenance-free CSS when adding more targets (to achieve it though the anchor has to be just before the div, but other CSS selectors than + could probably be used)

Comment: following up on my last comment, also see some useful variations at a comment reply I did on a related blog post: https://zoomicon.wordpress.com/2017/11/25/howto-show-block-on-anchor-hover-and-click-to-keep-open-with-css/#comment-17356

Answer (score 2):

yes you can do this with only css,first creat < div > with a specific width and height and overflow to hidden,then place your stuff in this div beside eachother

```
<a href="#firstWindow">firstWindow</a>
<a href="#secondWindow">secondWindow</a>
<a href="#thirdWindow">thirdWindow</a>
<div class="window">
    <div id="firstWindow" class="window">
         firstWindow
    </div>
    <div id="secondWindow" class="window">
         secondWindow
    </div>
    <div id="thirdWindow" class="window">
         thirdWindow
    </div>
</div>

.window{
   width:300px;
   height:300px;
   overflow:hidden;
 }
```

something like above;
note that you can use this html/css if you have a constant height,the height of your stuff should be the same.