# Show and hide content with link or anchor

Tags: html, css, anchor, show-hide, target

Been looking for an easy-to-use CSS only solution to show content on target from a link to an anchor on another page, and at the same time hide the rest of the content on the very same page.

Stumbled upon this old post: [CSS - show / hide content with anchor name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18849520/css-show-hide-content-with-anchor-name)

Where the second answer:

```
<a href="#firstWindow">firstWindow</a>
<a href="#secondWindow">secondWindow</a>
<a href="#thirdWindow">thirdWindow</a>
<div class="window">
    <div id="firstWindow" class="window">
         firstWindow
    </div>
    <div id="secondWindow" class="window">
         secondWindow
    </div>
    <div id="thirdWindow" class="window">
         thirdWindow
    </div>
</div>

.window{
   width:300px;
   height:300px;
   overflow:hidden;
 }
```

Kind of solved my problem. However I only get the `firstWindow` to show - where the other links: `secondWindow` and `thirdWindow` only show the `firstWindow` content.

I bet there's a easy solution to my problem. Greatly appreciate some help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thought to give this as a comment, but would be hard to read. Its a DRY  improvement of @Sanchit Patiyal answer. AFAIK its supported pretty well:

```css
[id$="Window"] {
  display:none;
}
[id$="Window"]:target {
  display:block;
}

.window{
   width:300px;
   height:300px;
   overflow:hidden;
 }
```

```html
<a href="#firstWindow">firstWindow</a>
<a href="#secondWindow">secondWindow</a>
<a href="#thirdWindow">thirdWindow</a>
<div class="window">
    <div id="firstWindow" class="window">
         firstWindow
    </div>
    <div id="secondWindow" class="window">
         secondWindow
    </div>
    <div id="thirdWindow" class="window">
         thirdWindow
    </div>
</div>
```