# Set DIV display:block on A:hover Trigger (using only CSS)

Tags: css, html, hover

I'm trying to trigger a `div` from `display:none;` to `display:block;` when a link is hovered. I've tried to achieve the reaction through an adjacent sibling selector but the target `div` doesn't change from `none` to `block`. I think it's because I'm not defining the correct hierarchy, but I have no idea what else to try.

```
<div id="home_bar">
    <div id="welcome_left">
        I’m <a href="#" id="name">Anthony</a>.
    </div>

    <div id="welcome_right">
        <div id="name_desc">I love lamp.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The above HTML is powered by the following CSS:

```
#home_bar {
display: table-row;
width: 888px;
border: 1px solid red;
margin-top: 80px;
}

#welcome_left {
letter-spacing: -1px;
font-size: 36pt;
line-height: 36pt;
width: 666px;
color: #606060;
cursor: default;
display: table-cell;
float: left;
}

#welcome_right {
float: right;
width: 200px;
display: table-cell;
position: relative;
}

#name:hover { color: #00A68D; cursor: default; }

#name_desc {
top: 50px;
position: absolute;
display: none;
}

#name:hover + #name_desc { display: block; }
```

I previously tried the following as the last line:

```
#home_bar > #name:hover + #name_desc { display: block; }
```

As that seemed like the right course of action based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210033/show-div-on-hover-with-only-css/5210074#5210074?newreg=94305c199f374591a504fbc92c326dde), but I still can't achieve the desired affect (to be clear, the desired effect is: hover a link on the left, trigger the appearance of content on the right).

Any thoughts with regards to what I could be doing differently here? I'm hoping to avoid jQuery if I can as I'm normally a lot more comfortable working with CSS, but I'm completely stuck.

Answer (score 3):

The adjacent sibling combinator has to be used with sibling elements. In this instance, `#welcome_left` and `#welcome_right` are the siblings. Therefore, when `#welcome_left` is hovered over, you will select the sibling `#welcome_right`'s child element `#name_desc`.

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/fnDN2/)

```css
#welcome_left:hover + #welcome_right #name_desc {
    display: block;
}
```

Unfortunately, you can't use the following, because `#name` and `#welcome_right` are not sibling elements. In CSS, you *currently* can't transverse the DOM, therefore there aren't any parent selectors.

```css
#name:hover + #welcome_right #name_desc {
    display: block; /* doesn't work because they aren't siblings .. */
}
```