# How to Show/Hide div when hovering to any Link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mouseevent

I am facing one small Issue in displaying/hiding any div on hovering any anchor tag.

**Currently I tried with Mouseenter and MouseLeave functions but Its not smooth.**

Clickable Link:`<a class="clickmeToSeeDiv" href="##"></a>`

JS code:

```
    $('.clickmeToSeeDiv').live("mouseenter",function(){
        $('.leftborderActive').show();
    });
    $('.clickmeToSeeDiv').live("mouseleave",function(){
        $('.leftborderActive').hide();          

    });
```

Above code sometime works sometimes not.
Please suggest if you all have any Idea or a better solution.

Thanks
Sham

Comment: You have answer here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210033/show-div-on-hover-with-only-css][1] with only css.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210033/show-div-on-hover-with-only-css

Comment: I would suggest not using `live`, but `on`.

Answer (score 3):

live event is deprecated, use [`.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) instead (Attach an event handler function for one or more events to the selected elements).

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".leftborderActive").hide(); // hide div on DOM ready
    $( ".clickmeToSeeDiv" ).mouseenter(function() { // anchor mouseover event
        $(".leftborderActive").show(); // show div
    }).mouseleave(function() { //anchor mouseleave event
        $(".leftborderActive").hide(); //hide div
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/RDyq2/)**

or

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(".leftborderActive").hide();
    $(document).on('mouseenter mouseleave','.clickmeToSeeDiv',function(){
        $('.leftborderActive').toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: He should use `on` even if it is not delegated (just sayin').

Answer (score 2):

the method 'live' is deprecated, use 'on' instead.

```
$(document).on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.clickToSeeDiv', OnDivClick);

function OnDivClick(){
    $('.clickToSeeDiv').toggle();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try JQuery's animate functions or set a timer on the show and hide methods so that they make the div operate a little more smoothely.

Also, make sure to cancel any previous events when you call the enter or leave methods so that the animations don't stack.