# Generating automated links based on automated image retrieval system (Freewall.js - Grid Layout)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, layout, grid

I have been using the [Freewall jQuery plugin](http://vnjs.net/www/project/freewall/) in order to generate a responsive grid-based image gallery. Such a piece of work, I have to say. However, I have been struggling to find a way to make the pictures linkable, given that the images of the gallery are retrieved in an automated manner:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var temp = "<div class='cell' style='width:{width}px; height: {height}px; background-image: url(grid-images/photo/{index}.jpg)'></div>";
        var w = 280, h = 320, html = '', limitItem = 15;
        for (var i = 0; i < limitItem; ++i) {
            html += temp.replace(/\{height\}/g, h).replace(/\{width\}/g, w).replace("{index}", i + 1);
        }
        $("#freewall").html(html);

        var wall = new freewall("#freewall");
        wall.reset({
            selector: '.cell',
            animate: true,
            cellW: 280,
            cellH: 320,
            onResize: function() {
                wall.refresh();
            }
        });
        wall.fitWidth();
        // for scroll bar appear;
        $(window).trigger("resize");
    </script>
```

In other versions of the code, Minh has placed the code of every single picture of the gallery in the html file. What I find particularly useful is the automated retrieval of the JS code and I would like to know... Is there an automated way of associating each of the pictures to a certain link, thus making the pictures linkable?

That would be: *1* to **A**, *2* to **B**, *3* to **C** and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not 100% sure what you would like to see but perhaps you could do something like this (trying to keep it the same way you've been doing it) :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var links = ["A.html", "B.html", "C.html"];
        var titles = ["titleA", "titleB", "titleC"];
        var temp = "<a href='{link}' ><div class='cell' style='width:{width}px; height: {height}px; background-image: url(grid-images/photo/{index}.jpg)'><div class='showOnHover'>{title}</div></div></a>";
        var w = 280, h = 320, html = '', limitItem = 15;
        for (var i = 0; i < limitItem; ++i) {
            html += temp.replace(/\{height\}/g, h).replace(/\{width\}/g, w).replace("{index}", i + 1).replace("{link}", links[i]).replace("{title}", titles[i]);
        }
        $("#freewall").html(html);

        var wall = new freewall("#freewall");
        wall.reset({
            selector: '.cell',
            animate: true,
            cellW: 280,
            cellH: 320,
            onResize: function() {
                wall.refresh();
            }
        });
        wall.fitWidth();
        // for scroll bar appear;
        $(window).trigger("resize");
    </script>
```

Comment: The system retrieves the images using the i+1 parameter. I want every image to be linkable, which, as I understand it, should be done associating every element of the array of images to an array of html files, just as you did in your code.

However, I am unable to make your code work. There is some syntax missing, I think. I have uploaded the whole Javascript code on the original post. Hope it helps! ;)

Comment: You pretty much understood what I was trying to do, however not too sure what's wrong with the current syntax. I'll check again.
Also, what are you trying to link the images to ? (just to give me an idea)

Comment: Simply put, each image will take the user to a new html page. I understand this must be also automated so that the code always makes i+1 correspond to A.html, i+2 to B.html and i+3 to C.html. Thanks for the help, btw it is much appreciated!

Comment: I tested this and it works rather well, edited my answer to include all your code so it's easier for you to test it. Note that arrays start at 0 and not at 1 so A.html corresponds to links[0] so we should not do i+1 to get the first one.

Comment: Great ! Pretty cool library by the way, might use it too later :)

Comment: It is indeed really comprehensive. 
One more thing, though @Gabriel... Would it be possible to add some text when hovering over the different images? Following the same logic, it should be an array of text strings specified under a different var. Do you reckon this would be hard to achieve? Like, linking back to the CSS and everything...

Comment: Yeah you can have the title='{title}' attribute on your div or on the a. You could have an array for those values and do exactly like the links

Comment: I understand what you say but I am not sure I know howt

Comment: Changed my answer, hope this helps

Comment: Ohh good. You are only missing to add title='{title}' in <a href..> (or in the <div>)

Comment: Thanks! ;) What I am looking for is somewhat different, though. I am trying to put a block of text over the image that will only reveal on hover. I want to have some editing possibilities here, so that they all look the same but a different string of text is applied to each image as the array goes on.

Comment: I quoted you on the conversation with the author of the code, just in case you want to follow along or give me ha hand here.

Comment: Ohh there are many ways you can do this, CSS is your friend here. A bit too complicated to explain in a comment but take a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210033/show-div-on-hover-with-only-css

Comment: Oh cool. This is kind of what I am looking for. Do you think I can relate it to the JS function so that every time an element of the array is hovered over a different string of text will appear?

Comment: Yes, I edited my answer to show you how to do it. It's actually like before but I added a <div class='showOnHover'> inside the one with the image, you would only need to create the appropriate CSS

Comment: I am trying to learn some Javascript coding but it does take a while to digest. Even for some simple syntax  like this. You have been really helpful. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Please using this

```
var links = ["A.html", "B.html", "C.html"];
        var titles = ["titleA", "titleB", "titleC"];
        var temp = "<a href='{link}' title='{title}'><div class='cell' style='width:{width}px; height: {height}px; background-image: url(grid-images/photo/{index}.jpg)'></div></a>";
        var w = 280, h = 320, html = '', limitItem = 15;
        var index = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < limitItem; ++i) {
            index = i % 3;
            html += temp.replace(/\{height\}/g, h).replace(/\{width\}/g, w).replace("{index}", i + 1).replace("{link}", links[index]).replace("{title}", titles[index]);
        }
        $("#freewall").html(html);
```

follow the variable **index**

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer @mihn-nguyen! I am more looking for an array of strings of text that would _overlap_ the image, just as you are doing on other versions of the code, such as in http://goo.gl/jy1sCe. I want to have a text field over the image that will change as specified as the array goes on.

What @gabriel and you suggested is a response that is activated with the cursor hovering over the image. I would not have much editing control over this. I want the text to appear only when the cursor hovers over the images, but as text contained in a <div> or some other <html> element.