# Pull down Menu with different text displayed on selection?

Tags: html, css

I'm currently coding a pull down menu, much like the one discussed here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17996303/html-display-a-text-when-dropdown-menu-has-been-chosen

But when "Option 1" is selected I'd like it to display "X", when "Option 2" is selected I'd like it to display "Y", etc. I feel like I'm sniffing around the right code but I just can't seem to get it right.

It's a beast of a list (about 350 menu options), so I'll save you all from my code unless you really need it.

Comment: try something like this pure JS code http://jsfiddle.net/m77PD/

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways to achieve what you want. The simplest would probably be using [jQuery's html() method](https://api.jquery.com/html/).

You could also use [plain JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML).

Or [CSS states](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210033/show-div-on-hover-with-only-css), depending on your layout.