# hide/unhide HTML portions by hovering?

Tags: javascript, html, css

more precisely, I've seen websites where there's a kind of header image, which loops through 3-4 different images, and each image is referenced by a dot, and you can pick the image you want by clicking the dot as well. I'm sure everyone has seen this somewhere.
as an example, go to http://www.tsunamitsolutions.com/

my question is, how do I make these dots appear/disappear when I hover on the image (like on the site I shared above) is it javascript or can this be accomplished just in the CSS with the "hover" style.

In other words, can hovering over one html portion/div/section make another div/section appear/disappear just by using CSS?

Comment: It can be done with either, I will try and get a CSS answer for you. have you a example of your current slider ?

Comment: Hi sorry, no I havent tried it myself yet because I wasn't sure how to implement it

Comment: `#sliderContainer #buttonContainer { display: none; }`

`#sliderContainer:hover #buttonContainer { display: block; }`

Comment: ahhh I like it, thank you very much!

Comment: See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210033/show-div-on-hover-with-only-css) for more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done in the CSS.

Assuming the dots/arrows are child elements of banner container, you can do something like:

```
.bannerContainerClass .dotClass {
   display: none;
}

.bannerContainerClass:hover .dotClass {
   display: block;
}
```

You can also do it in jQuery if you need effects like fade:

```
$(".bannerContainerClass").hover(function() {
   $(this).children(".dotClass").fadeIn(500);
}, function() {
   $(this).children(".dotClass").fadeOut(500);
});
```

The jQuery method can be modified to work even if the dots aren't children of banner container.

Comment: I see, thank you, so if anything is not a child of the same container, Javascript is required?

Comment: Note that `display:none` collapses the space. If you use `opacity:0` you won't have that problem.

Comment: @AbdulAhmad: Yes, but more correctly, the element must be a "descendant" of the hover-container (or else you simply can't select it with CSS). It doesn't have to be a direct child.

Comment: Thanks, Casey. I should have clarified.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish it using Jquery and javascript. As in any website header images there is a tag for image one tag for collection of those points. 
Suppose.

`<div id="header_image">
..code for header image..
</div>`

which is header tag. and there is a tag which cointains the points.

`<div id="points_container">
..code for points...
</div>`

Now in its javascript code if you want to disappear "points_container" tag when mouse is hovered over "header_image".and appears again when mouse is hovered out, you can write in its Javascript code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#header_image").hover(function(){
$("#points_container").hide();
},function(){
$("points_container").show();
});
});
```

Comment: Try reading OP's question, amigo. ;) *"In other words, can hovering over one html portion/div/section make another div/section appear/disappear **just by using CSS**?"*

Comment: sorry !! have no idea how to do it in CSS :(

Comment: Don't be sorry; just don't clutter OP's question, bud. He isn't asking for alternatives. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use css on hover with either the visibility attribute or opacity attribute to hide an object, the full implementation of a gallery widget like this is somewhat more complicated though. CSS solution:

```
.dots:hover
{
    opacity:0;
}
```

Makes anything with the dots class invisible on mouse over.

Or if you don't want it to take up any space when invisible:

```
.dots:hover
{
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: but this is modifying the element being hovered on right? I want to modify/show a different element by hovering on this one

Answer (score 0):

Try this with simple CSS transitions, like this

**HTML**

```
<div id="parent"><br/><span class="bullets">* * * *</span></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.bullets{
opacity:1;
}

#parent:hover > .bullets{
opacity:0;
transition: opacity .2s ease-out;
-moz-transition: opacity .2s ease-out;
-webkit-transition: opacity .2s ease-out;
-o-transition: opacity .2s ease-out;
}
```

**[FIDDLE HERE>>](http://jsfiddle.net/prasanthkc/63BQE/3/)**

Comment: Unnecessary transitions?

Comment: @CaseyFalk what is unnecessary in this?

Comment: "transitions" -- which currently make up 40% of the code. They are nice, but clutter the "meat" of the answer. ;)

Comment: @CaseyFalk but his reference site has got that fadeout effect and he want it to do with using pure css.

Comment: I would argue that OP's question only asks how to "hide/unhide HTML portions by hovering" and not how to "fade in/fade out" elements; but, fair enough. Depends on OP's definition of "example" I guess. ;)

Comment: @CaseyFalk its not hide/unhide, its appear/disappear like the eg site :-)

Comment: It **is** "hide/unhide" in the question title. But whatevs. : )