# make div appear only on active state of another

Tags: html, css

what I want is that `div` with id `makeMeWork` to be visible only when div with id `clickMe` is clicked.

the [fiddle  link](http://jsfiddle.net/ad6hbb52/1/).

html:

```
<div class="showhim">Press ME<div class="showme">Working</div></div>
<div class="showme" id='makeMeWork'>Not Working</div> <div class="showhim" id='clickMe'>Press ME</div>
```

css:

```
.showme{ 
    display: none;
    background-color:red;
    width:200px;
    height:50px;
}
.showhim:active .showme{
    display : block;
    background-color:green;
}
```

I want this done purely through css as js and HTML part can no longer be modified.
I guess the major problem now is, there is no way to select previous child in css,

similar questions : [is-there-a-previous-sibling-selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-selector) and [show-div-on-hover-with-only-css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210033/show-div-on-hover-with-only-css)

Comment: [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tbnsoc3y/) wrap in a `div` and give styles for parent

Comment: @VitorinoFernandes please post it as answer, i will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do something like this

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/tbnsoc3y/

wrapping your content in `div` for eg like i have done

```
<div class="cont">
    <div class="showme" id='makeMeWork'>Not Working</div>
    <div class="showhim" id='clickMe'>Press ME</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Right Now There is No previous selection of sibling available but it will be soon in css4 which has been drafted in w3c and they are working on it , ill tell use jquery or css hack !

[Read the article](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/01/21/sneak-peek-future-selectors-level-4/)