# How to use :hover for one element and chnage another class css proprties

Tags: html, css

I have on doubt about css, Can any one please help me.

I have one span element

```
<span>Please Click</span>
```

and i have one div element:

```
<div>
       <a>Click 1</a>
       <a>Click 2</a>
</div>
```

at starting point it **div element** should be `display : hidden`

i want,  when mouse over on **span element** div elements class property should change `display: visible`

can any one please help how will do it using  **css?**

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show div on hover with only CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210033/show-div-on-hover-with-only-css)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the power of css selectors to do this. I've just made a simple example below:

```css
a {
  display: none;
}
div:hover a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>hello?<a>hi!</a>
</div>
```

Please kindly note that my example is using a nested `a` tag. Your example might look like:

```css
a {
  display: none;
}
span:hover a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Please Click
       <a>Click 1</a>
       <a>Click 2</a>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @jbutler483,

My Html like this:
   <th> 
       <span>Click </span>
       <div>
            <a>Click1 </a>
            <a>Click2</a>
      </div>

i want when mouse over on span element, i need show div..

can you please help me out this one 

Thank you so much

Comment: From seeing you edited comment, i'm gussing you had to change your markup slightly?