# Need to display a div on hover of other div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an element set to visibility:hidden and i need it to change to visible on hover, i tried this with javascript with no luck

HTML

```
<div class="options">
  <div id="option-1" onmouseover="dis()"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="pic-1"></div>
```

CSS

```
#option-1{
  width:100px;
  height:20px;
  background:#fff;
  position:relative;
  z-index:999;
  top:0;left:0;
}
#pic-1{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:99;
  background:#f0f;
  visibility:hidden;
}
```

Javascript

```
function dis(){
  document.getElementById("pic-1").style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

Comment: Why don't you do this with CSS?

Comment: already tried it but didn't work since pic-1 is not inside or in the same div as option-1

Comment: Missed that... My bad.

Comment: You can do it using only css.

Here is an example: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210033/show-div-on-hover-with-only-css

Comment: @ZeekIFJ No, he can't do this with CSS because `#option-1` is a child of `#pic-1`'s sibling. Even with Selectors Level 4 gets implemented, CSS still won't be able to use the parent selector; DOM traversal with JavaScript will be required.

Answer (score 2):

html:

```
<div class="options">
  <div id="option-1" onmouseover="showx();"  onmouseout="hidex();"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="pic-1"></div>
```

css:

```
#option-1{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#pic-1{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:99;
  background:#f0f;
  visibility:hidden;
}
```

js

```
function showx(){
  document.getElementById("pic-1").style.visibility = "visible";
}

function hidex(){
  document.getElementById("pic-1").style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

codepen link:  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bNrdrN

Comment: it is not working for you on your browser? did it work in codepen ?