# Hide & show multiple links on a page using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am working on a product shortlist feature. I have grid view for each product & I have provided a shortlist link for each of the grid cell. Now I want to hide all these links in each cell initially on page load & show a specific link within the cell when a user hovers on that particular cell and again hide that link when user moves the cursor out of the cell. This cell is nothing but a div.

The shortlist link is within a div having the class product-grid-item.This div is nothing but a grid cell on which I want to hover. Actually using toggle function I am able to show/hide the shortlist link, but my code is generating multiple grid cells i,e div so when i hover on a particular grid the link is getting displayed but it also display all the links within the other grids as well.I just only want to show the particular link within the grid on which user hovers not all the links within the other grid cells.

How can I achieve this using jQuery? This is my code:

```
<?php foreach ($products as $index=>$product):?>
  <div class="product-grid-item grid-cell">
    <div class="shortlist" style="display: none; float:right;">
    <?php
      echo CHtml::ajaxLink('<i class="fa fa-star"></i> Shortlist',Yii::app()->createUrl('productshortlist/shortlistproduct'),
        array('data'=>array('productId' => $product->product_id),
        'dataType'=>'text',
        'type'=>'get',
        'success'=>'function(result)
                    {
                      if(result == "Success")
                      {
                        alert("Product Added to the shortlist successfully.");
                        $("#shortlistedProduct").prop("disabled",true);
                      }
                      else
                        $("#shortlist_product_error").html(result);
                      }'),
        array('id'=>'shortlistedProduct'.$index)
      );
    ?>
    </div>
  </div>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Output:

```
 <a id="shortlistedProduct0" href="#"><i class="fa fa-star"></i> Shortlist</a> 
 <a id="shortlistedProduct1" href="#"><i class="fa fa-star"></i> Shortlist</a>
```

Suggested but not working script:

```
<script>
    $(".product-grid-item").hover(function()
    {
        $(".shortlist").toggle();
    }
   );
</script>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please take a minute and read the [help] to see how to ask questions here. Hint: We want to see HTML and CODE. Other hint: Read the jQuery docs on [.hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) and [.show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/)

Comment: Please add the GENERATED HTML. This is a jQuery question, not a PHP question - If you click the code snippet icon you can format the question with html and jQuery

Comment: Actually that PHP code generates a normal hyperlink and using foreach loop it generates multiple hyperlinks with different ids.Something like this: <a id="shortlistedProduct0" href="#"><i class="fa fa-star"></i> Shortlist</a> <a id="shortlistedProduct1" href="#"><i class="fa fa-star"></i> Shortlist</a>  and so on.

Comment: So add that to the question instead of having us do PHP rendering in our heads.. Where is the link near the list that you want to hover?

Comment: If you add the link or text to hover, and include jQuery, your code works: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/yb8e39zy/

Comment: The shortlist link is within a div having the class  product-grid-item.This div is nothing but a grid cell on which I want to hover.Actually using toggle function I am able to show/hide the shortlist link, but my code is generating multiple grid cells i,e div so when i hover on a particular grid the link is getting displayed but it also display all the links within the other grids as well.I just only want to show the particular link within the grid on which user hovers not all the links within the other grid cells.

Comment: Finally we have all information

Comment: Why don't you suggest him the css solution with hover. Instead of toggleing, can we add a css to the outher div to show inner div on hover?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now with all your information available to us, we can finally answer your question

```js
$(function () {
    $(".product-grid-item").hover(function () {
        $(this).find(".shortlist").toggle();
    });
});
```

```css
.shortlist {display: none; float:right;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product-grid-item grid-cell">Hover on me
    <div class="shortlist">
        <a id="shortlistedProduct0" href="#"><i class="fa fa-star"></i> Shortlist</a>
        <a id="shortlistedProduct1" href="#"><i class="fa fa-star"></i> Shortlist</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="product-grid-item grid-cell">Hover on me
    <div class="shortlist">
        <a id="shortlistedProduct0" href="#"><i class="fa fa-star"></i> Shortlist</a>
        <a id="shortlistedProduct1" href="#"><i class="fa fa-star"></i> Shortlist</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir.Now this code is working fine for me.Thank you for your time & patience. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try to add a css for the div-s to show or hide the links using the `hover css selector` - http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp

I still think that even if you can't solve this by adding `css hover selector` for your `product-grid-item div` to show `shortlist` div, then use `jQuery` only to add htat `css` instead of `jQuery toggle()` or `jQuery hover()`.

Comment: Poor reference. Here are examples http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210033/show-div-on-hover-with-only-css

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Below is my code

Comment: Hello Hovo. Thanks for the reply I have added the HTML code & script.Hope you will understand my question now.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have included jQuery if yes then try this code

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {


    $(".product-grid-item").hover(function()
    {
        $(".shortlist").toggle();
    }
   );
});

</script>
```

Comment: @mplungjan please explain what you want??

Comment: I was mistaken. Your code works if there is content to hover over in the div (the link not shown in OPs code) - like this https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/yb8e39zy/

Comment: @mplungjan make sure you did not put `</a>` to  `display: none` in css or jquery

Comment: I wrongly expected a hover with only one statement to toggle (show) when hovered and then toggle(hide) again when hovered again. So I was thinking you needed mouseenter and out to show/hide, but you do not. It works with toggle alone

Comment: PS: The shortlist is display none in his code so no need to hide from jQuery