# Showing element on hover issue in CSS

Tags: css

This is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2xnow6f8/2/. What I am trying to achieve is:
- on hover statement on li to show my submenu. I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210033/show-div-on-hover-with-only-css)
. I tried to reproduce it but with no result. Can someone help me with this ?
This is the code:

```
ul.mainmenu li:hover + div.header ul.mainmenu li div.submenu {display: block}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want `hover` on `li` then you have to change in your HTML structure `div.submenu` should be next to `li`, then only your css will work, Take a look to following structure i have made some changes in `Css` also:

```css
div.submenu {
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    display: none;
}
div.submenu {
    background: #FFF none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
    top: 35px;
    border-top: 5px solid #FFF;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #FFF;
    z-index: 15;
}
li:hover ~ div.submenu {display: block}
```

```html
<ul class="mainmenu">
    <li>
        <a href="/index.php?id=5" title="Trouwen">Trouwen</a>
    </li>
    <div class="submenu">
        <ul class="submenulist">

            <li>
                <a href="/index.php?id=1478" title="Beoordelingen van gasten">Beoordelingen van gasten</a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="/index.php?id=1222" title="Best Deal Day's">Best Deal Day's</a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="/index.php?id=1466" title="Top Trouw Deal">Top Trouw Deal</a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="/index.php?id=1415" title="Menukaart">Menukaart</a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="/index.php?id=60" title="Mogelijkheden">Mogelijkheden</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</ul>
```

Comment: Then its nearly impossible with css. You can use `Jquery` or `Javascript` for this.

Answer (score 1):

Its because `ul.submenu` is not directly after `li`

The `+` selector works like this:

```
Selects all <ul class='submenu'> elements that are placed immediately after <li> elements.
```

Since there are none,

Try adding `a:hover` instead of `li:hover`

http://jsfiddle.net/2xnow6f8/5/

For only `hover` on desktop:

http://jsfiddle.net/2xnow6f8/6/

Comment: Thax but i do not want for a:hover I want li:hover. I need this for mobile version. because hover statement transforms in click in mobile. and when the user click on the item, instead of showing the submenu it will be redirected to url form my a tag

Comment: If I understood you correctly, add a media query to turn off the hover.

Comment: my <li> has width:100%. So when the user clicks on my <li> then show the submenu. Now the user have to click on the <a> as you post me. Are u understanding what i want :D ?

Comment: Try putting the submenu directly under li and see if that works!

Answer (score 0):

Just change this selector:

```
ul.mainmenu li:hover + div.header ul.mainmenu li div.submenu
```

into this:

```
ul.mainmenu li:hover > div.submenu
```

Details of the changes:

- Removed unneeded elements in selector (for example `div.header` is not present in your html
- Changed the `+` selector into `>` to reflect the right position of the embedded sumenu

Comment: Added more details to my answer to be more accurate.