# Hiding Div with CSS not working?

Tags: html, css

So according to this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210033/show-div-on-hover-with-only-css)

I should be able to hide a div with CSS and appear on hover but for some reason I'm not getting the same hover effect on the image I put it on which happens to be on the top corner of this [Link](http://chocobento.x10.mx/wp/)

Any suggestion on why it might now be working?

Here's the CSS I used

```
.user-image {
  float:none !important;
  right: 0;
  margin-right: 4.5%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
}

.user-image img {
  width: 65px !important;
  height: 65px !important;
  margin-top: -15px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 32px;
}

.user-image li {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: white;
  display: none;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-left: -35px; 
}

.user-image img:hover + .user-image li {
  display: block;
}
```

Here's the HTML

```
<div class="user-image">
<img src="http://chocobento.x10.mx/wp/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/1-300x300.jpg" width="180" height="180" alt="itslino" class="avatar avatar-180 wp-user-avatar wp-user-avatar-180 alignnone photo">
<li> Test </li>
<li> Test 2 </li>
</div>
```

Comment: Please include the HTML as well. And preferably with a fiddle or a snippet.

Comment: https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fchocobento.x10.mx%2Fwp%2F

Comment: Flagging for: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.* - Please [edit] your question to include enough code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @Roope There I fixed it and added HTML

Comment: @BSMP There added the HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work:

```
.user-image img:hover + .user-image li {
  display: block;
}
```

You're selecting any `li` that is a descendant of a `.user-image`, that is a sibling of an `img:hover` that is a descendant of a `.user-image`.

I can't give you an actual solution because we need to see the html that's being returned by your php tag, but if your `img` is inside of the `li` that's hidden, then you should hide/show when the `li` is hovered, not the `img`.

---

**Update**

Based on the html you provided, you just need to drop the second `.user-image` from your selector:

```
.user-image img:hover + li {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: I can show you that as well then hold let me re-edit again.

Comment: I added the HTML you wanted to see

Comment: That actually worked sorta, only one li [list item] shows. Do I just add another li to make the other show?

Comment: I found a away, I just added a second code version underneath looks the same but added another + li and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `opacity` to accomplish this like the example below

```css
.user-image {
    opacity: 0;
    background-color: red;
}
.user-image:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="user-image">
    <a href="">Test hover thing here</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm planning on putting links so hiding it would still allow them to be clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Make some changes to your code something like this way

replace your code with this codes.

```
    <div class="user-image">
    <a><img  src="http://chocobento.x10.mx/wp/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/1-300x300.jpg" width="180" height="180" alt="itslino" class="avatar avatar-180 wp-user-avatar wp-user-avatar-180 alignnone photo"></a>
    <div class="user-image">
        <li> Test </li>
        <li>Test 2 </li>
    </div>
```

and  style

```
a:hover + .user-image li  {
display: block;
}
```

[CLICK HERE TO SEE YOUR CODE IN FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dyfba4ap/1/)

Make adequate changes if necessary..

gud luck

Comment: I edited the question, I want it to hide which is easy but on hover display itself.

Comment: The first link I added takes you to a stackoverflow example on how they made it work but despite me following the steps I can't replicate it.

Comment: go to fiddle.com and make a fiddle code.and send the link.

Comment: Do you want to hide that particular div while hover.or hide it permenantly after mouse hover.

Comment: I want to make it appear when I hover over the img basically.

Comment: Why would you use js?