# Display a div with :hover

Tags: css

I don't want to use js to do what I want to do. So I want to display a div when I hover it without use the js.

Here is my css :

```
.testHover{
  width : 100px;
  height : 100px; 
  position : relative;
}

.background{
   width : 100px;
  height : 100px;
  background : pink;
}

.cachee{
  visibility : hidden;
  background : green;
  position : absolute;
  top :0px;
  z-index : 999;
}

.cachee:hover{
  visibility : visible;
}
```

I made a jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/g8ud4ck0/3/

So I want to display the text just by hover it, but it doesn't work, how can I do please ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using only CSS, show div on hover over <a>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210033/using-only-css-show-div-on-hover-over-a)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you're doing it at the moment doesn't work because you can't `hover` a `div` that is hidden. What you need to do is create a parent `div` that is visible, capture the `hover` event and show the child `div` when that happens.

HTML

```
<div class="parent">Hover me <div class="child">I'm hidden</div></div>
```

CSS

```
.child{visibility: hidden;}
.parent:hover .child{visibility: visible;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't hover an element with `display:none` or `visibility:hidden` because it is supposed to be not exist, instead do one of these:

1. change `visibility:hidden` to `opacity:0`, then trigger it 1 when hover over it

   [**JS Fiddle 1**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/32fn43cL/)

   ```css
   .testHover{
     width : 100px;
     height : 100px; 
     position : relative;
   }
   .background{
      width : 100px;
     height : 100px;
     background : pink;
   }
   .cachee{
     opacity:0;
     background : green;
     position : absolute;
     top :0px;
     z-index : 999;
   }
   .cachee:hover{
     opacity:1;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <div class="testHover">
     <div class="background"></div>
     <div class="cachee"><a>Je suis une div cachée</a></div >
   </div>
   ```
2. use the hover over the preceding div `.background` to trigger the visibility of the `.cachee` using this rule `.background:hover ~ .cachee,.cachee:hover`

   [**JS Fiddle 2**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/3d0jxrv2/1/)

   ```css
   .testHover{
     width : 100px;
     height : 100px; 
     position : relative;
   }
   .background{
      width : 100px;
     height : 100px;
     background : pink;
   }
   .cachee{
     visibility : hidden;
     background : green;
     position : absolute;
     top :0px;
     z-index : 999;
   }
   .background:hover ~ .cachee,.cachee:hover {
     visibility : visible;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <div class="testHover">
     <div class="background"></div>
     <div class="cachee"><a>Je suis une div cachée</a></div >  
   </div>
   ```
3. trigger the visibility on parent hover

   [**JS Fiddle 3**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/3d0jxrv2/2/)

   ```css
   .testHover{
     width : 100px;
     height : 100px; 
     position : relative;
   }
   .background{
      width : 100px;
     height : 100px;
     background : pink;
   }
   .cachee{
     visibility : hidden;
     background : green;
     position : absolute;
     top :0px;
     z-index : 999;
   }
   .testHover:hover .cachee {
     visibility : visible;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <div class="testHover">
     <div class="background"></div>
     <div class="cachee"><a>Je suis une div cachée</a></div >  
   </div>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can't hover a hidden element. But you can hover an element with `opacity: 0`.

```css
.cachee {
  opacity: 0;
}
.cachee:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```css
.testHover {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
.background {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: pink;
}
.cachee {
  opacity: 0;
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 999;
}
.cachee:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="testHover">
  <div class="background">
  </div>
  <div class="cachee">
    <a>Je suis une div cachée</a>
  </div>
</div>
```