# CSS hover over <li> and reveal hidden <ul>

Tags: css, hover, show, hidden

Here is my code as simple as possible for convenience.

```css
            #hidden {
              display: none;
            }
            #visible:hover + #hidden {
              display: block;
            }
```

```html
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
  <ul>
    <li id="visible">
      Names
      <ul id="hidden">
        <li>name 1</li>
        <li>name 2</li>
        <li>name 3</li>
        <li>name 4</li>
      </ul>
    </li>

  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

So I have tried to follow this code [example from this webiste](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210033/using-only-css-show-div-on-hover-over-a#_=_) and do the same with my code, but it didn't worked.

Could you explain to me why? And show me the correct way ?

Comment: In the example, div was adjacent element to anchor element. Did you try keeping `ul` element adjacent to `li` element instead of making it child of `li` element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because element with id `#hidden` is child and not sibling of the element with id `#visible`. You can use [Descendant selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors):

```css
#hidden {
  display: none;
}
#visible:hover #hidden {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="visible">
    Names
    <ul id="hidden">
      <li>name 1</li>
      <li>name 2</li>
      <li>name 3</li>
      <li>name 4</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

</ul>
```

**References**

[Adjacent sibling selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because you are using the [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) (`+`). `#hidden` is a descendent of `#visible` so no intermediary selector is required:

```css
#hidden {
  display: none;
}

#visible:hover #hidden {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="visible">
    Names
    <ul id="hidden">
      <li>name 1</li>
      <li>name 2</li>
      <li>name 3</li>
      <li>name 4</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Your current selector would work for a similar structure to the following, which is obviously invalid:

```
<ul>
  <li id="visible">
    Names
  </li>
  <ul id="hidden"> /* #hidden is now a sibling of #visible */
      <li>name 1</li>
      <li>name 2</li>
      <li>name 3</li>
      <li>name 4</li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```