# Making a different div visible on mouse enter

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a div that you can hover the mouse over, and another one will appear. This is what I have so far...

**html**

```
<div id="buttons">
<div id="box"></div>
<div id="content">content here</div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
#box {
position:absolute;
width: 10vw;
height: 10vw;
background-color: blue;
}

#content {
position:absolute;
width: 10vw;
height: 10vw;
background-color: red;
visibility: hidden;
}
```

**jquery**

```
$( "box" )
.mouseover(function() {
$( "content").style.visibility( "visible" );
})
```

any help you be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You need '#' for the selectors to specify IDs (ex. $("#box")).

Comment: with pure css: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210033/using-only-css-show-div-on-hover-over-a

Comment: Awesome! it works now, thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up JQuery with pure javascript in many places...

Either do this in JQuery:

```
$("#box").mouseover(function() {
    $("#content").css("visibility", "visible");
});
```

or do this in pure javascript:

```
document.getElementById("box").onmouseover = function() {
    document.getElementById("content").style.visibility = "visible";
};
```

**But you can achieve the same effect using css only:**

```css
#box {
  position:absolute;
  width: 10vw;
  height: 10vw;
  background-color: blue;
}

#content {
  position:absolute;
  width: 10vw;
  height: 10vw;
  background-color: red;
  visibility: hidden;
}

#box:hover + #content {
  pointer-events: none;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div id="buttons">
  <div id="box"></div>
  <div id="content">content here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The 'content' selector needs '#'

Comment: @KiiroSora09 - Oops.. sorry, copy paste. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
('#box').hover(
  function () {
    $('#content').show(); //or css('visibility','visible');
  }, 
  function () {
    $('#content').hide(); //or css('visibility','hidden');
  }
);
```

This will show/hide the div. You miss the '#'

Answer (score 0):

See the working fiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/8dpcuztk/

Here, Instead of visibility attribute, play with display : none.

So in essence, you will use show and hide functionality for the second div.

Also, your selector are not working because you are searching for Id and must use # in front of div id.

```
$("#box").on("mouseover", function() {
    $("#content").show();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/).

```
$("#box").on('mouseenter', function() {
 $("#content").append("<div class='box'></div>");
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/32eckm71/40/

Answer (score 0):

```js
$( "#box" ).hover(
  function() {
    $( "#content" ).fadeIn(); //.show();
  },
  function(){
    $("#content").fadeOut(); //hide();
  }
);
```

```css
#buttons{position:relative;}
#box {
position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:10vw;height:10vw;background-color:blue;cursor:pointer;
}

#content {
position:absolute;top:100px;left:100px;width:10vw;height:10vw;background-color:red;
display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="buttons">
  <div id="box"></div>
  <div id="content">content here</div>
</div>
```