# Show div when <a> element is hovered

Tags: jquery, html, css

Easy to explain. I want to make something like dropdown menu. When I hover on element (for example ) -  appears div block, which disappears on leaving `<a>` element or `div` block.

```
<a>Element to hover</a>
<div>I'm not gonna disappear until u leave me or my <a> bro</div>
```

I hope it would be easy for you guys to help me. Thanks in advance!

What have I tried? 
I went by the simplest way, but this doesn't work as I wanted. I did it in css, smth like

```
 a:hover div {
display: block;
}
```

But when I leave div, it disappears. So I need the other solution? How can I do this?

Comment: So where's your CSS/jQuery?  What have you tried?

Comment: What about your question should we take into account so that we don't equate "help me" with "do it for me"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what a simple CSS solution would look like using the sibling selector.

```css
.nav
{
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 1px;
}

.nav:hover + .menu, .menu:hover
{
  display: block;
}

.menu {
  display:none;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 1px;
}
```

```html
<a class="nav">Element to hover</a>
<div class="menu">I'm not gonna disappear until u leave me or my a bro</div>
```

Comment: you should include the reference to the original [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210033/using-only-css-show-div-on-hover-over-a)

Comment: Thanks alot man! U didn't waste ur time for teaching me how to describe my problem, but just helped me. Wish u luck

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam that post is  not actually what i was looking for

Comment: the message was for @abney317 and yes that post includes the answer you are loking for

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam That post doesn't include keeping the div open when it is hovered over as well. Similar question though. Looks like the 2nd highest voted answer in that is what he was looking for.

Comment: @abney317 Nah, man, there div is included in other div. In my case, these two elements are separated