# How can I display the X only in single list when I hover on it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, redux

I am facing the problem when I am going to hover in single list. I just want to display the X only on a single list when I hover it. But it displays in all the when I go to hover on a single one.

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react/cjs/react.development";
import "./list.css";

function List({ items }) {
  const [over, setOver] = useState(false);

  const mouseOver = () => {
    setOver(!over);
  };

  return (
    <ul>
      {items.map((item, i) => {
        return (
          <>
            <li
              onMouseOver={mouseOver}
              onMouseOut={mouseOver}
              style={{
                borderRight: `5px solid ${item.amount < 0 ? "red" : "green"}`,
              }}
              key={i}
              className="item-name"
            >
              <p>{item.itemName}</p>
              <p>{item.amount}</p>
              <p style={{ display: over ? "block" : "none" }}>X</p>
            </li>
          </>
        );
      })}
    </ul>
  );
}

export default List;
```

[image]

Comment: Does this help?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210033/using-only-css-show-div-on-hover-over-another-element

Comment: No It doesn't help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In each item you should  have `over` state, and it should not be shared for all items. I wrote it like this:

```js
// import React from "react";
// import "./list.css";

const items = [
  { id: 1, amount: 50000, itemName: "Salary" },
  { id: 2, amount: -500, itemName: "Gym" },
  { id: 3, amount: -5000, itemName: "Bill" },
];

const List = () => {
  return (
    <ul>
      {items.map((item) => (
        <ListItem key={item.id} item={item} />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}

// export default List;

const ListItem = ({ item }) => {
  const [over, setOver] = React.useState(false);

  const mouseOver = () => {
    setOver(!over);
  };

  return (
    <li
      onMouseOver={mouseOver}
      onMouseOut={mouseOver}
      style={{
        border: "1px solid black",
        borderRight: `5px solid ${item.amount < 0 ? "red" : "green"}`,
      }}
      className="item-name"
    >
      <p>{item.itemName}</p>
      <p>{item.amount}</p>
      <p style={{ display: over ? "block" : "none" }}>X</p>
    </li>
  );
};


ReactDOM.render(<List />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: You are welcome, please mark answer as correct if it works for you, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You're facing this problem because all of the `li`s share the same `over` state. You either need to somehow define an state for every component, or use pure css for this - which is the method I prefer:

## Pure CSS Mehtod:

```css
.item-name .the-x {
  display: none;
}

.item-name:hover .the-x {
  display: block;
}
```

and change the X part to:

```
<li
    onMouseOver={mouseOver} /* remove this */
    onMouseOut={mouseOver}  /* remove this */
    ...
>
    ...
    <p style={{ display: over ? "block" : "none" }}>X</p> /* remove this */
    <p className="the-x">X</p> /* use this */
    ...
</li>
```

Instead of `display: none/block` you can use `opacity:0/1` or `visibility:hidden/visible`. use any CSS property you prefer