# How to hover div by hovering a different div?

Tags: html, css

I have a div that contains an image of a product. Below it I have the title of the product which is a link. I know how to hover directly on the product title, but I want it to change color when hovering on the image.

Sorry to trivial question, but I'm new and trying to learn. I also found some references, but here I want to deepen the discussion and understand what is the best practice.

```css
.downloads-box {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
}

.cover_image {
   width: 100%;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   justify-content: space-between;
}

.linkable-box {
   width: 100%;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   justify-content: space-between;
}

.cover_image .product_image {
   opacity: 1;
   transition: 0.2s all;
   margin-bottom: 6px;
}

.cover_image .product_image:hover {
   opacity: 0.85;
}

.product_image > img {
   box-shadow: rgb(0 0 0 / 15%) 0px 10px 10px -10px;
   border-radius: 6px;
}

/*Product Title*/
.prod_title {
   color: #21262F;
   overflow: hidden;
   white-space: nowrap;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   max-width: 500px;
   transition: all 0.2s;
}
```

```html
 <div class="downloads-box">
          <a class="linkable-box" href="#"> 
            <div class="cover_image">
              <span class="product_image"><img src="https://www.commonwealthfund.org/sites/default/files/styles/countries_hero_desktop/public/country_image_Japan.jpg?h=fcdfd899&itok=bPWz69YA" alt="Paris" style="width:150px"></span>
              <span class="prod_title t2" title="title-example">My prooduct Title</span>
            </div> 
          </a>
 </div>
```

Comment: why warp the image inside a span? that makes no sense. would be easy to solve if you wouldn't do that.

Comment: Actually the html code contains some php elements, I just changed to ask the question here and make everything easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SImple remove the span that is wrapping the image and use the `+` selector to select the following span:

```css
/* Solution #1 */
.cover_image img:hover + span {
  color: red;
}


/* original CSS */
.downloads-box {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
}

.cover_image {
   width: 100%;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   justify-content: space-between;
}

.linkable-box {
   width: 100%;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   justify-content: space-between;
}

.cover_image .product_image {
   opacity: 1;
   transition: 0.2s all;
   margin-bottom: 6px;
}

.cover_image .product_image:hover {
   opacity: 0.85;
}

.product_image > img {
   box-shadow: rgb(0 0 0 / 15%) 0px 10px 10px -10px;
   border-radius: 6px;
}

/*Product Title*/
.prod_title {
   color: #21262F;
   overflow: hidden;
   white-space: nowrap;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   max-width: 500px;
   transition: all 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="downloads-box">
          <a class="linkable-box" href="#"> 
            <div class="cover_image">
              <img src="https://www.commonwealthfund.org/sites/default/files/styles/countries_hero_desktop/public/country_image_Japan.jpg?h=fcdfd899&itok=bPWz69YA" alt="Paris" style="width:150px">
              <span class="prod_title t2" title="title-example">My prooduct Title</span>
            </div> 
          </a>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply add this:

```
.product_image:hover + .prod_title  {
   color: red;
}
```

If you want to learn more, there is an entire dedicated post here [Using only CSS, show div on hover over another element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210033/using-only-css-show-div-on-hover-over-another-element)

```css
.downloads-box {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
}

.cover_image {
   width: 100%;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   justify-content: space-between;
}

.linkable-box {
   width: 100%;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   justify-content: space-between;
}

.cover_image .product_image {
   opacity: 1;
   transition: 0.2s all;
   margin-bottom: 6px;
}

.cover_image .product_image:hover {
   opacity: 0.85;
}

.product_image > img {
   box-shadow: rgb(0 0 0 / 15%) 0px 10px 10px -10px;
   border-radius: 6px;
}

/*Product Title*/
.prod_title {
   color: #21262F;
   overflow: hidden;
   white-space: nowrap;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   max-width: 500px;
   transition: all 0.2s;
}


.product_image:hover + .prod_title  {
   color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="downloads-box">
          <a class="linkable-box" href="#"> 
            <div class="cover_image">
              <span class="product_image"><img src="https://www.commonwealthfund.org/sites/default/files/styles/countries_hero_desktop/public/country_image_Japan.jpg?h=fcdfd899&itok=bPWz69YA" alt="Paris" style="width:150px"></span>
              <span class="prod_title t2" title="title-example">My prooduct Title</span>
            </div> 
          </a>
 </div>
```

Comment: note, that the color does not only change when you hover over the image. It changes already when you hover the container.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite a simple, but kind of tricky solution. Because both elements with `product_image` and `prod_title` classes are in the same `div` with the class of `cover_image`, they are called **sibling elements**.

```
.cover_image > .product_image:hover + .prod_title {
      color: green; 
 }
```

The `+` after the `product_image:hover` indicates that the element after that is his sibling.